# Reverse Count after threshold

Tags: python, rhino3d

I am feeding a number slider in RhinoPython to increment the y value. I wish to reverse the increment when y equals a certain value. I have figured out how to make it negative, but that is not what I'm after. Sorry, for the simplicity of this question and thank you. In short the number slider increments the variable and once it reaches 45, then it would count down with every increment of the number slider.

```
len = 45
inc = float(.1)

if y >= len:
    y *= -inc
print (y)
```

Comment: You want to add the increment or multiply by it ? Also the problem with your code is that once you do `y *= -inc` the `if` condition is not verified anymore so the program stops

Comment: Yes this makes sense. I wish to subtract from the variable once the condition is met.

Comment: then replace `y*=-inc` by `y -= inc` and add a `if` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't call a variable `len`, because it is a name of standard library function.
If I understood the question correctly, the code would be

```
threshold = 45
inc = .1
y = 0

while True:  # goes forever, put your own code here
    if y >= threshold:
        inc *= -1
    y += inc
    print (y)
```

After y reaches 45, it start counting down. No stop condition when you count down though, it's an infinite cycle here

Comment: Thanks again, I am implementing this: `threshold = x/2
inc = float(.1)

while true:
    if y >= len:
        inc *= -1
    y += inc
    
    if y <= 0:
        break` but it is crashing my computer when the condition is met

Comment: Yes, it got close, but as I mentioned I cannot figure out a proper exit as: `if y <= 0: break` does not return any values. Do you know why this is?

Comment: which value do you want it to return? `break` supposed to only quit the `while` cycle without doing anything else

Comment: what do you mean by crashing computer?

Comment: it only crashed when I forgot to initialize the `y value`. Currently, it does nothing if I input `break` to exit the loop. Is there a better way? Thanks again

Comment: if you want it to print `y`, add the `print(y)` statement after the `y += inc` line

Comment: I cannot figure out how to have y return values. I am incrementing numbers as an input. This could be messing up the loop I suppose.